# How safe is it to go to Baghdad?

Tags: us-citizens, safety, middle-east, iraq

How safe is it to go to current day Baghdad as a tall American white dude who speaks only English?

Safe in terms of bodily harm, abduction and/or robbery. Can I roam around in tourist areas of Baghdad without any enhanced danger due to my background?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your question as stated is too broad and opinion-based to be answerable. You haven't told us the purpose of the trip, what you plan to do, or where you plan to stay, or what research into the matter you've already completed. But as of April 9, 2019, the official U.S. State Department guidance is ***[Do Not Travel](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Iraq.html): Do not travel to Iraq due to terrorism, kidnapping, and armed conflict. U.S. citizens in Iraq are at high risk for violence and kidnapping.***

Comment: IMHO this question can be improved and is borderline acceptable.

Comment: @choster "You haven't told us the purpose of the trip, what you plan to do, or where you plan to stay" - are those necessary? I don't think those who encounter terrorism, kidnapping or armed conflict would say safety in Baghdad is "opinion based" - it seems from the top answer that it's pretty objective. Also, it's from an authoritative source (US govt). I would vote for reopening this if I had the rep.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ## Iraq - Level 4: Do Not Travel

Source: [U.S. Department of State Travel Advisory, April 9, 2019](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Iraq.html)